# Maven clean install both jar and war

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my spring project 'Calorie counter', I have the following file structure:

```
Calorie counter code/
   CalorieCounterWar/
     src/
     target/
     pom.xml
     ...
CalorieCounter/
   src/
   target/
   pom.xml/
   ...
```

Everytime I have to do `mvn clean install` both in `CaloriecCounter` and `CalorieCounterWar` to build the project. Without writing a script to do it together, is there a way to modifiy/add `pom.xml` to do both buids by single `mvn clean install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a parent project which has both projects as modules.

Example from http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>simple-weather</module>
        <module>simple-webapp</module>
    </modules>

    ....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. One thing, do I need to include anything in the `pom.xml` of the child projects, eg, <parent> <\parent>?

Comment: No.  You can refer to a super pom, which may be - but do not have to be - the parent pom, but that is just to pick up common settings.  Also, the text in the module tag is the _relative directory path_ to the project, not the module name itself.